# Matlab, Random Cell Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array Q, wich contains questions. And a Logical vector containing 1/0 as true / false and in same order as Q like this:

```
Q = {'A ball is squared: ' 'My computer is slow: ' 'A triangle has 3 corners: '};
A = {0 1 1};
```

I would then make a Q_random, containing the questions from Q but in randomly order and a A_random contaning the logical numbers which respond to the Q_random. I've come up with this code, but i not sure that this is the best way to do it.

Could I use another method, which is more simple and effective ?

```
Q = {'A ball is squared: ' 'My computer is slow: ' 'A triangle has 3 corners: '};
A = {0 1 1};
Q_random = cell(1,numel(Q));
A_random = cell(1,numel(Q));

i = 1;
while (i <= numel(Q));
random_number = randi(numel(Q));
if isempty(Q_random{random_number});
    Q_random(random_number) = Q(i);
    A_random(random_number) = A(i);
    i = i + 1;
else
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate randomly ordered indexes

```
rand_ind=randperm(length(Q));
```

and then use the random indexes to generate the randomly permuted cell arrays

```
Q_random=Q(rand_ind);
A_random=A(rand_ind);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262196/how-can-i-take-a-random-sample-from-a-cell-array/18263443#18263443) answer to a previous related question may also be worth looking at.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I want, much more simple than my code